# Matrix in python containing cos and sin

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am a beginner in python. I have this matrix:

```
    Mat RX = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
          1, 0,         0,          0,
          0, cos(roll), -sin(roll), 0,
          0, sin(roll), cos(roll),  0,
          0, 0,         0,          1);
```

How do I make this in python?  It gives error when I try something like this:

```
    MatrixX = np.mat('1,2,3;cos(roll),6,7')
```

Comment: You haven't said what is roll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the string constructor to `np.mat`. it's primarily there to ease matlab users in, and only works in the simplest cases. It also creates a `np.matrix`, which is generally not recommended to use.

All you need here is:

```
np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, np.cos(roll)]
])
```

(line-wrapping optional)

Answer (score 0):

If you intepret `cos()`, and then construct the string, this can work:

**Code:**

```
MatrixX = np.mat('1,2,3;%s,6,7' % cos(roll))
```

**To Test:**

```
>>> np.mat('1,2;3,%s' % math.cos(2))
matrix([[ 1.        ,  2.        ],
        [ 3.        , -0.41614684]])
```

Comment: Good attempt, but `roll = np.inf` gives `TypeError: Invalid data string supplied: nan`. Roundtripping data through strings is always a bad idea

Comment: @Eric, What?  Op is clearly a matlab user.  And the fact that cos(inf) is undefined is significant how?

Comment: `cos(inf)` is well-defined to return `nan`, so I would expect the result to be a matrix containing `nan` - but `np.mat` balks when given an unusual string. More importantly, it also loses precision.

Comment: @Eric, Fair enough, but I am pretty sure that if his autopilot gets a roll angle of infinity it is going to have other problems.

Comment: Yeah, you're almost certainly looking at an error anyway in the cases this matters - but `TypeError` isn't what you'd be expecting